# Why is my seemingly self-contained web page deaf to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

I wanted to see if I could take the elements of a jsfiddle and put it into a single page, add the few things necessary, and run it in my browser.

BTW, it works perfectly fine in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/QCrXG/2/), but not as a "naked" html file.

I added, I think, the necessary html (IOW, the stuff that jsfiddle provides behind the scenes), plus the requisite references to the CDN jQuery, jQueryUI js files, and a jQueryUI css file.

I put the CSS inside the page in a style section.

I put the jQuery in a script section (which includes "plugin" code prior to the ready handler).

Here is the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Platypus Criteria example</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<style>
h1 {
    color: chocolate;
    font-family:'Segoe UI Light';
}
body {
    background-color: oldlace;
}
form {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
legend {
    font-family:'Century Gothic', Verdana, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: navy;
}
.staticLabel {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Consolas, Candara, sans-serif;
}
.checkboxGroups1Col { width: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid chocolate; }
.checkboxGroups2Col { width: 400px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid chocolate; }
.checkboxGroups3Col { width: 600px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid chocolate; }
.checkboxGroups4Col { width: 800px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid chocolate; }
.checkboxGroups5Col { width: 1000px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid chocolate; }
label { display: inline-block; width: 200px; }

#dbills, #WebbedFeet {
    min-height: 200px;
}
.submitButton {
    background-color: SkyBlue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <h1>Platypus Criteria</h1>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Date Range</legend>
        <label for="BeginDate" class="staticLabel">Begin Date</label>
        <input id="BeginDate" />
        <label for="BeginTime" class="staticLabel">Begin Time</label>
        <input id="BeginTime" value="00:00:00" />
        <br/>
        <label for="EndDate" class="staticLabel">End Date</label>
        <input id="EndDate" />
        <label for="EndTime" class="staticLabel">End Time</label>
        <input id="EndTime" value="23:59:59" />
    </fieldset>
        <br/>
        <label for="UPC" class="staticLabel">UPC Starts with</label>
        <input id="UPC" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="accordion">
            <h3 id="deptHeader">Duckbills (selected: <span>all</span>)</h3>
            <div id="dbills" class="checkboxGroups4Col">
            </div>
            <h3 id="WebbedFeetHeader">WebbedFeet (selected: <span>all</span>)</h3>
            <div id="WebbedFeet" class="checkboxGroups4Col">
           </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" class="submitButton" value="Determine dbills and WebbedFeet selected" id="submitButton" />
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        appendAllCheck: function () {
            var selectors = $('<div class="selectors"></div>').appendTo(this)
                .append('<button>Select all</button><button>Deselect all</button>');
            selectors.find('button').click(function () {
                var checked = $(this).text() == 'Select all';
                $(this).closest('.selectors').parent()
                    .find('[name]:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                return false;
            });
            return this;
        },
        appendCheckboxes: function (name, labels, props) {
            var container = this;
            $.each(labels, function (i, l) {
                var label = $.isPlainObject(labels) ? i : l,
                    value = $.isPlainObject(labels) ? l : i;
                $('<label>').append(
                $('<input>', {
                    'type': 'checkbox',
                        'name': name
                }).val(value).prop(props||{}),
                label).appendTo(container);
            });
            return this;
        },
        checkedBoxes: function () {
            return this.find(':checked').map(function () {
                return $(this).parent().text();
            }).get();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function() {

var dbillsArray = [];
for (var i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
    dbillsArray.push(i);
}

var WebbedFeetArray = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    WebbedFeetArray.push(i);
}

$('#BeginDate, #EndDate').datepicker();
$('#accordion').accordion();
$('button').button();
$('#dbills').appendAllCheck().appendCheckboxes('dbillsCheckboxList', dbillsArray, {
    checked: true
});
$('#WebbedFeet').appendAllCheck().appendCheckboxes('WebbedFeetCheckboxList', WebbedFeetArray, {
    checked: true
});
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    dbillsList = $('#dbills').checkedBoxes();
    $('#deptHeader span').html(dbillsList.join(", "));
    WebbedFeetList = $('#WebbedFeet').checkedBoxes();
    $('#WebbedFeetHeader span').html( WebbedFeetList.join(", "));
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Is it possible for this to work? If so, what have I omitted or blunderbusted?

Also: why is the page so pison slow to load?

### UPDATE

This way of working seems handy for small "applets" or utilities ('quick-and-dirty' type things),  that can be run without having to deploy to a server; even if you need to use a .js file that is not hosted on a CDN, you can simply save a local copy of it and reference it like so:

```
<script src="checkboxplugin.js"></script>
```

(this example assumes the .js file and the .html file are living side-by-side as "siblings" in the same folder).

Comment: Are you running this on a server like WAMP etc. If not, the `//` will have to be replace with `http://`

Comment: I'm must opening the file from Explorer; of course, it opens a page in my browser (Chrome, BTW), but is achingly slow and seems to ignore jQuery.

Comment: The `style` tag should be within `<head/>`

Comment: string.replace('must', 'just');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things.
If you're not using a webserver but opening the file directly in the browser you'll need to change:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And you should add the script tags at the bottom of the file ***BEFORE*** the closing `</body>` tag, not after it, and the style tags should be inside the `<head>` tags, i.e. before the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: Perfect; works like a charmer, and is faster than a speeding ballet dancer.